# No Secure Random Number Generators Available in JDK

Tags: java, random, numbers, generator, security

I am currently running JDK 6 on Windows 7 and have installed the Unlimited Strength Policy Files. I wrote a Java app some time ago which used to work but now fails, giving an error message indicating that the SHA1PRNG SecureRandom is not available. I have tried printing a list of cryptographic providers available on the platform and it would appear that there are no secure random number generators available - does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Turns out the Sun provider which provides the SHA1PRNG wasn't installed - needed to call Security.addProvider() to add it back in.

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You must've been messing around your policy files because it is installed out of the box. Glad you got it working though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) the SHA1PRNG is available out of the box with JDK6. You don't need need to install any additional policy files.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you are getting a NoSuchAllgorithmException thrown because your installation no longer proves Pseudo Random Number Generator "SHA1PRNG", I would recomend having a look [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#ProviderImplReq) for info on how Algorithm are provided and used.